# How to create an inline anonymous function, for immediate use in a function call?

Tags: swift, syntax, parameters, anonymous-function

I have this Swift function which I created which takes a function as a param:

```
func doMath(_ f:(_ i1 : Int, _ i2 : Int) -> 
          (), _ i1: Int, _ i2: Int) {
    print("doing Math")
    f(i1, i2)
}
```

The function takes two params (both of Int) and returns nothing.

*I can successfully call that method with the following code, using a non-anonymous function.*

```
func add(_ m1:Int, _ m2: Int){
    print (m1 + m2)
}

doMath(add, 3,5)
```

When doMath is called, it prints:

> doing Math

and then calls the add function,
which then prints:

> 8

*What syntax allows calling the `doMath` function with an anonymous function?*

**What I've Tried**

- I'm reading the book, [iOS 12 Programming Fundamentals with Swift by Matt Neuberg](https://amzn.to/2S2CsKs) but he skips explaining anonymous methods with params.
- I've googled and SOed but can't find a swift example that I can figure out.
- I've tried many variations and the following is my closest but I get the error shown below:

---

```
doMath(5,8, { 
   (m1:Int, m2:Int) -> ()  in  
   print(m1 * m2) 
 })
```

I get an error that states:

[image: error msg]

Comment: Your last attempt is almost right, you only got the order of parameters wrong: `doMath({ .... }, 5,8)`

Comment: Oh, wait, the body comes first and then the params!?!  I've tried everything, except that.  Never would've tried it.  I'll try it now.  EDIT - Tried it and it worked !!! That syntax!! I kind of hate it.  But maybe I'll love it later.  xD Argh!

Comment: **You** defined `func doMath` taking a closure as the first argument, and two integers as second and third argument.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, it's the way I defined the other method.  All because I'm learning Swift and attempting to create samples.  Okay, write those two things up in an answer and I'm happy to mark as answer. Meanwhile, I'll go back and re-read Neuberg's explanations too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`func doMath` – as you defined it – takes a closure as the first argument,
and two integers as second and third argument. Therefore you call it as

```
doMath({
    (m1:Int, m2:Int) -> ()  in
    print(m1 * m2)
}, 5, 8)
```

or with shorthand parameters:

```
doMath({ print($0 * $1) }, 5, 8)
```

If you change the function definition to take the closure as the last 
parameter

```
func doMath(_ i1: Int, _ i2: Int, _ f:(_ i1 : Int, _ i2 : Int) -> ()) {
    print("doing Math")
    f(i1, i2)
}
```

then you would call it as

```
doMath(5, 8, { print($0 * $1) })
```

or, using the “trailing closure” syntax:

```
doMath(5, 8) { print($0 * $1) }
```

Comment: Thanks this got me to the place I needed to be and gave me additional information that is very valuable so I could understand other concepts more clearly.